# Alias for properties that exist only in subclasses (Hibernate Criteria)

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

Consider the class `Operation`, and its 3 subclasses:

```
 class Operation {}
 class OpA extends Operation { }
 class OpB extends Operation { Account account; }
 class OpC extends Operation { Account account; }
```

Only `OpB` and `OpC` have a field called `account`.

I want to query for the `account` property:

```
session.createCriteria(Operation.class)
       .add(Restrictions.eq("account", account))
       .list();
```

This works. Hibernate ignores the fact that both `Operation` and `OpA` have no field called `account`, and returns the
correct results for `OpB` and `OpC`.

However, now I also want to query for the **account owner**, and order by it. I then create the alias `_account` for `account`:

```
session.createCriteria(Operation.class)
       .add(Restrictions.eq("account", account))
       .createAlias("account", "_account")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("_account.owner", "John"))
       .addOrder(Order.asc("_account.owner"))
       .list();
```

This fails. There are 2 separate tables for the account (from `OpB` and `OpC`), so Hibernate complains:

```
Not unique table/alias: 'account1_'
```

**My question: How can I query for both the account and the account owner, using only `Criteria` (no SQL, HQL) in the simplest possible way?**

Comment: What would the desired SQL look like?

Comment: @Pedrag: Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution. It works only **partially**:

```
 Criterion subQ1 = Subqueries.propertyIn("id",
                       DetachedCriteria.forClass(OpB.class)
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("account", account))
                            .createAlias("account", "_account")
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("_account.owner", "John"))
                            .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("id")));

 Criterion subQ2 = Subqueries.propertyIn("id",
                       DetachedCriteria.forClass(OpC.class)
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("account", account))
                            .createAlias("account", "_account")
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("_account.owner", "John"))
                            .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("id")));

 session.createCriteria(Operacao.class)
        .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
            .add(subQ1)
            .add(subQ2))
        .list();
```

It works as long as I don't add order: `.addOrder(Order.asc("_account.owner"))`.

The order cannot be added to the `Subqueries`, because it would have no effect.
And it cannot be added to the `Criteria`, because it doesn't accept the alias.

Maybe there is a way to tweak this, or maybe this solution is too complicated and there is an easier one?

Answer (score 3):

The two solutions below don't work. Both result in `Not unique table/alias: 'account1_'`.

I am posting them here to document what doesn't work, or maybe to give ideas to someone else, without complicating the question itself:

```
session.createCriteria(Operation.class)
       .createAlias("account", "_account")
       .add(
           Restrictions.and(
               Restrictions.or(
                   Property.forName("class").eq(OpB.class),
                   Property.forName("class").eq(OpC.class)),
               Restrictions.eq("account", account)
               Restrictions.eq("_account.owner", "John"))
               )
           )
       .list();
```

Without alias:

```
session.createCriteria(Operacao.class)
       .add(Restrictions.eq("account", account))
       .createCriteria("account")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("owner", "John"))
       .list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an `AccountOperation` abstract class as:

```
public abstract class AccountOperation extends Operation {
    public abstract Account getAccount();    
}
```

Now both `OpB` and `OpC` will extend `AccountOperation`.

Your query will become:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(AccountOperation.class, "op")
    .createAlias("op.account", "ac")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("ac", account))
    .addOrder(Order.asc("ac.owner"))
    .list();
```

Comment: Yes, my example is redundant, but it's just an example. My problem is the `Not unique table/alias: 'account1_'` exception.

Comment: Sorry Vlad, I was out of office and couldn't test it before. Well, your example gives me this exception: `Not unique table/alias: 'ac1_'`.

Comment: With the IN directive I get `java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` at `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap`.

Comment: Vlad, classes are being given numbers, for some reason, so something like `Restrictions.in("op.class", new Integer[]{1,2})` finds them (the corresponding numbers change each time). But even when it selects only classes that contain `account`, the same `Not unique table/alias: 'ac1_'` exception occurs.

Comment: I can't actually create a new Interface. The subclasses I need are only known at runtime. Thank you for your help.